# jquery animations when appending html

Tags: jquery, animation

I am trying to create the fadeIn effect when prepending a `<UL>` using Jquery, but the animation effect never appears on the page. Am i doing a mistake in specifying the fadeIn effect?

This is how my code looks

```
<UL id="myUL">
   <LI> First Item <LI>
   <LI> Second Item <LI>
   <LI> Third Item <LI>
   <LI> Fourth Item <LI>
<UL>
```

The Jquery is as follows (on button click)

```
var liData = "<LI> A New Item </LI>";
$('#myUL').prepend(liData).fadeIn('slow');
```

Though the `<LI>` appears correctly on the page, i donot see the fadeIn effect on the page. Am i doing something wrong in binding the data and the effect on the item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Added the display:none style, so Its not visible as soon as you prepend it and somewhat inverted the jQuery line.

```
var liData = '<LI style="display:none"> A New Item </LI>';
$(liData).prependTo('#myUL').fadeIn('slow');
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sPeHy/4/

Answer (score 2):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/djky6/)

This should do it

```
$('#myUL').prepend(liData).find("li:first").hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

Basically you were selecting the `ul` and not the `li`. Also you need to hide it before you fade it in or it will just fade from 100% to 100%, and you will see nothing in effect.

Comment: This will give flicker effect. It's better for the element to be hidden by default.

Comment: @Shef Granted but that wasn't the posters question. :P  The poster wanted to know why he couldn't see his fade in effect; not how to optimize the existing function.  I chose to simply answer the question and in the simplest most understandable way I could.

Answer (score 1):

First, the item should be added by an event so you can notice it, not at the load time.

Second, the newly added list item should be by default hidden so it can be displayed with a fade-in effect.

Here is the code:

```
$('#add_item').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var liData = '<LI style="display:none"> A New Item </LI>';
    $(liData)
        .prependTo('#myUL')
        .fadeIn('slow'); 
});
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/Huvqy/)

Comment: You can avoid the `find` if you use `prependTo`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#myUL').prepend($("<LI> A New Item </LI>").hide().fadeIn('slow'));
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sPeHy/3/

Comment: That's an extra unnecessary jQuery object.

Comment: you're using a second jquery object too. You're just adding the overhead of finding it after pre-pending.

Comment: :p busted... But you could easily just `delete` it or drop out of it's scope.